# Arduino Shield Pin Conflict

Tags: pins

I have a Freetronics [Etherten](http://littlebirdelectronics.com.au/products/etherten-100-arduino-compatible-with-onboard-ethernet) and am trying to use the [NFC Shield](http://littlebirdelectronics.com.au/products/nfc-shield-v2-0) - both the board and shield are trying to use Pins D10,D11,D12,D13

So my question - Is there an elegant way to have these two work together.  This really applies to any combination of shield with conflicting pins.  I'm thinking maybe use some in between headers or M/F jumper wires?

Is there a neat way to do it?

Comment: I blather on about something similar here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/motor-shield-and-wireless-transceiver-compete-for-same-pins/3895#3895

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11002
"The Go-Between Shield “goes between” two shields that aren’t compatible and effectively reassigns the pins. This trickery is achieved by isolating the top and bottom sides of the shield with surface mount headers and breaking them out into tables of jumpers that can be bridged to divert signals to and from different pins."

Comment: D11-D13 are the SPI pins. So you should only move D10 (SS) to another pin.